# How to display amount of passed time as a humanly readable string like "10 seconds ago" or "3 hours ago"?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting human readable relative times and dates from a unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260558/getting-human-readable-relative-times-and-dates-from-a-unix-timestamp)

All I have is a `NSTimeInterval` which is in the past. How can I convert that to a "`humanly readable`" string like "`10 seconds ago`" or "`3 hours ago`"?

Comment: i guess you are getting time passed in a float already?

Comment: Did you try searching, there are a bunch of questions here on SO. This one ie: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7809899/294661

Answer (score 2):

NSTimeInterval gives you seconds.

Once you are confirmed with the seconds you can use % and / to find days, hours, minutes and seconds.

See this demo:

```
NSInteger seconds = totalSecondsSinceStart % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (totalSecondsSinceStart / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = totalSecondsSinceStart / (60 * 60);
NSString *result = NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld hour %02ld minutues %02ld seconds ago", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Output will be like:

```
01 hours 34 minutes 49 seconds ago
```

Comment: At WWDC there was a talk about Apple providing an API for that with localized output.

Answer (score 0):

More formatted so you don't see 0 hours 0 minutes and 34 seconds.

```
+(NSString *)returnRelativeTime:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    int timeSince = [date timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1;

    int days    = (timeSince / (3600 * 24));
    int hours   = (timeSince / 3600)- (days *24);
    int minutes = (timeSince % 3600) / 60;
//    int seconds = (timeSince % 3600) %  60;
//    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",hours ,minutes, seconds];
    if (days >0) {
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01d days %01d hours ago",days, hours];
    }
    else if (hours == 0) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01dm ago", minutes];
    }
    else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%01dh %01dm ago", hours ,minutes];
    }

}
```